# Use jsafeJCEFIPS.jar OSGi

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, jce, jar-signing

Has anyone tried using jsafeJCEFIPS.jar OSGi? The jar is signed, I can't convert it to a bundle. I tried to embedded as jar in bundle, but it is always throws 
java.lang.SecurityException: "JsafeJCE provider is disabled, a FIPS 140 required self-integrity check failed" when I try to create a instance of JsafeJCE object.

It looks JsafeJCE can't check itself integrity(signature etc.)successfully.
I print out jsafeJCE.class.getProtectionDomain, it is (inputstream:bundle-name.jar ).

Any idea how to get jsafeJCE works in OSGi, I'm using Apache Felix.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ugly workaround is to add RSA jars in system class path and expose these packages thru org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation